# In Corda 3, getting Quasar ClassReader exceptions when running runNodes

Tags: corda

When I run the `runNodes` task to start nodes in Corda 3, I get the following exception:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by Capsule (file:/D:/Code/LearnBlockChain/cordapp-template-kotlin/build/nodes/PartyB/corda-webserver.jar) to field com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.mbsInterceptor
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of Capsule
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5009
[quasar] ERROR: while transforming jdk/internal/vm/PostVMInitHook: null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
       at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
       at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
       at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.QuasarInstrumentor.instrumentClass(QuasarInstrumentor.java:120)
       at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.QuasarInstrumentor.instrumentClass(QuasarInstrumentor.java:94)
       at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.JavaAgent$Transformer.transform(JavaAgent.java:209)
       at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(Unknown Source)
       at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
       at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
[quasar] ERROR: while transforming jdk/internal/math/FloatingDecimal: null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see this issue if you use the wrong version of the Oracle JDK. Corda requires the Oracle JDK 8 JVM, with a minimum supported version of 8u131.

Comment: This is the same fix with version 4.4 as well.